# Kendo ui PivotGrid / Remote binding Error

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Kendo UI PivotGrid sample demo for Local binding working fine, but for Remote binding it is throwing following error when click on **"Include Fields".**

Below is the reference link:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/pivotgrid/remote-flat-data-binding

Anybody have any idea about the same?

Thanks
Raju Chauhan

[image: Kendo UI PivotGrid Remote binding throwing error when click over Include Fields]

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue, you can keep track of it here:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/1940

Comment: Thank you so much.